# Icon not showing in for Custom Uniform Type Identifier (UTI) in iOS/Swift project

Tags: ios, user-interface, icons, uti

I successfully created a custom Uniform Type Identifier (UTI) for my
iOS 11 / Swift 4 / iPad only application with the help of [Technical Q&A QA1587](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1587/_index.html). I am able to open the file with my app through the following function in the `AppDelegate` class: `optional func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool`

By default, the icon for files of this type is the App icon: e.g when using the Documents app, the icon is displayed correctly. However, the icon is **not** displayed in the AirDrop dialog. Instead the 'blank white sheet' icon is used:

[image]

How can I set the App icon (or some other custom icon) to be displayed in the AirDrop dialog? I know about the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` -> `CFBundleTypeIconFile` property of the `Info.plist` file. But I didn't manage to specify the icon so that it is reflected on the device.

Answer (score 0):

While recieving file from airdrop, you need to set preview in `activityViewController(_:thumbnailImageForActivityType:suggestedSize)` to be able to see what you want to see.